# Why RegDst control signal and the associated mux is put in the execution stage instead of the instruction decode stage?

Tags: mips, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

According to the book *Computer Organization and Design* by Patterson and Hennessy (5th edition) page 304, the *RegDst* control signal is being used in the execution stage of the datapath.
It acts as the selection bit for the mux that chooses the destination register from one of the two register addresses passed in the *ID/EX* pipeline register.

Why the *RegDst* control signal and the associated mux are not put in the instruction decode stage (the stage immediately before the execution stage)? That way, we could have sent only the selected destination register address from [20-16] and [15-11] bits of the instruction in the *ID/EX* pipeline register, instead of sending both of them.
[image: MIPS datapath]

Comment: At first glance, I can't see any obvious reasons. Could this be for timing reasons? The mux depends on the result of the control unit but nothing else in the ID stage does so moving the mux back might make the stage longer and reduce the maximum cpu frequency

Comment: @DarioPetrillo: Yeah, the dependency argument looks sensible here.  Or maybe it's left over from simplifying a a pipeline that has to do hazard detection somewhere, to stall (e.g. on `mflo` after a `div` or `mult`) or set up bypass forwarding?  OTOH, I wouldn't be surprised if a real CPU has that mux as part of the Control unit, since the control unit needs to figure out the actual destination of every instruction to detect hazards, I think, so it needs those instruction fields as inputs.  And four 2:1 muxes is just four x 3 gates or so (plus one inverter)

Comment: That diagram doesn't show logic for bypass forwarding.  If it did, we would see it send all 3 possible registers fields, rs, rt, and rd to the pipeline registers.  So, in some sense, there'd be no saving of bits or wires by moving that mux to the preceding stage.